# bootstrap tabs not showing active when open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 tab-panes with various content in them. They work fine and they change when I click on them. Although for some reason they are not showing active when I click on them i.e. if I click on "Third Year" the background should change to blue as you can see for this piece of CSS:

```
.tabs .nav-tabs li.active a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #4582EC;
  border: 2px solid #4582EC;
}
```

Can anyone see why they are not changing to active when I click on them?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dngpqrwy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you take li as active class. just change this peace of code and it will work:

in HTML :

First Year

in CSS:

```
   .tabs .nav-tabs > li, .tabs .nav-pills > li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 180px;
 border: 2px solid #4582EC;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

.tabs .nav-tabs {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

}

.tabs .nav-tabs li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.tabs .nav-tabs li a {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 20px;
/*   padding: 10px 25px;
  border: 2px solid #4582EC; */
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #4582EC;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;

}

.tabs .nav-tabs li:hover {
  background: #4582EC;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #4582EC;
}
.tabs .nav-tabs li:hover a{
   color: #fff;
 }
.tabs .nav-tabs li.active > a{
  color: #fff;
}
li.active{
  background: #4582EC;
}
```

Comment: could you please tell me how to get the 4 tabs all the same width? :)